# What is the purpose of using a decision tree?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I don't understand what is the purpose of the decision tree? The way I see it is, it is a series of if-else. Why don't I just use if-else instead of using a decision tree? It is because it decreases the complexity of my code?

I am still spared from calculating entropy and information gain because there are prebuilt algorithms for them where I just plug in the rules right? (Like ID3)

Why do we use it with machine learning now? Because we don't even have to come up with the rules while before we needed to? The machine learns from the training data and based on the attributes it can predict a result?

Does implementing ML in my code decrease overhead more and it makes my code less complex, more effective, faster?